# Jackson deserilisation for spring-response-body

Tags: ajax, json, spring, jackson

The Json-Response-Body for my example-ajax call will not deserilise as expected. For testing purposes I want to return an empty JSON-Array.

```
JavaScript: JSON-Ajax-Call

saveFiles: function (files) {
            $.ajax({
                url: "SaveFile.do",
                type: "post",
                data: JSON.stringify(files),
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function (saved) {
                    showSaveResult(saved);
                }
            });
        },

Java-Controller:        

@RequestMapping(value="/SaveFile.do", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody public ArrayNode createSaveResult (@RequestBody Data[] entities, BindingResult result, Locale locale){
        ArrayNode jsonReturn = new ArrayNode(jsonNodeFactory);
        return jsonReturn;
}

Request:

[{key:value1},{key:value2}]

Response:

{"array":true,"elements":[],"containerNode":true,"valueAsText":null,"numberType":null,"fields":[],"fieldNames":[],
"null":false,"textValue":null,"booleanValue":false,"long":false,"valueNode":false,"missingNode":false,
"object":false,"pojo":false,"number":false,"integralNumber":false,"floatingPointNumber":false,"int":false,
"double":false,"bigDecimal":false,"bigInteger":false,"textual":false,"boolean":false,"binary":false,
"numberValue":null,"intValue":0,"longValue":0,"bigIntegerValue":0,"doubleValue":0.0,"decimalValue":0,
"binaryValue":null,"valueAsInt":0,"valueAsLong":0,"valueAsDouble":0.0,"valueAsBoolean":false}
```

Instead the response delivers the complete ArrayNode Object. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An `ArrayNode` is a Jackson representation of a single element of an array. If you simply return it, you're going to get the serialized version of `ArrayNode`, not an empty array element which is what you want.

You can either return a class that represents your expected data set:

```
private static class SaveResult {
    String key;
    String value;
}

@ResponseBody public SaveResult[] createSaveResult (@RequestBody Data[] entities, BindingResult result, Locale locale){
    return new SaveResult[0];
}
```

You could also build up the Json by hand and return the string as shown here ([How to create this json string using Jackson?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12594095/how-to-create-this-json-string-using-jackson)).

I lean heavily towards the first approach as I feel it is much more obvious with a quick read of the code.